# greater or = to a post value

Tags: php

Hi all i have a post value which i am checking to see if its been posted it has atleast 4 numbers (digits) this works perfect.

```
if (isset($_POST['year']) && 
      !preg_match('/([0-9]{4})/i', stripslashes(trim($_POST['year']))) ) {
```

now i want to check that the value is greater or = to a vairable and not sure how to achive what i need

i tried the below with no luck

```
$yearOff = date("Y")-150;
echo $yearOff;


    if (isset($_POST['year']) && 
            !preg_match('/([0-9]{4})/i', stripslashes(trim($_POST['year']))) 
            && $_POST['year'] > $yearOff ) {

                   $ageerrors[] = '<span class="error">
                                      You forgot enter your birth YEAR</span>';
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$yearOff = date("Y")-150;
echo $yearOff;

$input = @$_POST['year'];

if (!$input || strlen($input) !== 4 || $input < $yearoff) {
    ### MEEEP, ERROR ###
}
```

Explanation:

Input is set (not `null` which would be false), then it must have a string-length of four and finally it's numerical value must be higher or equal `$yearOff`.

I assigned the value of the input to it's own variable as well, because you only need to take it once out of `$_POST`.

As all these conditions are negated, I used the or `||` operator. Naturally the same can be expressed non-negated and with and:

```
if ($input && strlen($input) === 4 && $input >= $yearoff) {
    ### THIS IS CALL OKAY ###
}
```

To better debug this, the next step is to assign the validity to a variable as well:

```
$inputValid = $input && strlen($input) === 4 && $input >= $yearoff;
if (false === $inputValid) [
    ### MEEP, ERROR ####
}
```

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: Thinking to myself, _weird, never seen this person before..._ Then realized you used to be hakre...

Comment: @Michaela: Today is gender friday.

Comment: perfect great help, i used the first one and will look into adding other stuff based on yours and @Michael comments, this will also help with the rest of my code

Answer (score 2):

Rather than an `&&` you need an `||` OR condition to switch between the three possible invalid states (empty, not 4+ digits, or `<= $yearOff`:

```
if (!isset($_POST['year'])
   // Lose the stripslashes()...
   || !preg_match('/([0-9]{4})/i',trim($_POST['year']))
   || $_POST['year'] > $yearOff 
   ) {
    // Invalid...
}
```

Note: It isn't clear from your description whether you *want* the value to be `>= $yearOff` or you want it to be `< $yearOff`. In other words, the code above is testing for the invalid state. Use whichever operator is appropriate for the invalid state.

Note 2: To test for *at least 4 consecutive digits* in the regex, a better pattern is something like:

```
/\d{4,}/
// If it must be *only* digits and no other characters, anchor with ^$
/^\d{4,}$/
```

There's no need for the overhead of a `()` capture group.

Comment: thank you so much for you input i hve used @hakra solution which seems to works as i want it, thank you for the input in the regex its not a strong piont of mine

Comment: changed to if (!$input || !preg_match('/^\d{4,}$/',trim($_POST['year'])) || $input < $yearOff) {, thank you